# Unable to Remove Android Platform in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to remove the Android platform in my cordova app but I am unable. Help is appreciated!

> $ cordova platform remove android
>
> rm: could not remove directory (code
>   ENOTEMPTY): myapp\platforms\android/app
>
> rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY):
>   myapp\platforms\android/app rm: could not remove directory (code
>   ENOTEMPTY): myapp\platforms\android
>
> Removing platform android from config.xml file...

Not sure why, but I check to see if it is at least recognized as removed but it is not:

> $cordova platform
>
> Installed platforms:
>   android
>
> Available platforms:
>
> android ~7.0.0   browser ~5.0.1   ios ~4.5.4   osx ~4.0.1   windows
>   ~5.0.0   www ^3.12.0

If I go to re-add the android platform I get this:

> $ cordova platform add android
>
> Using cordova-fetch for
>   cordova-android@^7.0.0 (node:11012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   CordovaError: Platform android already added.
>       at C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform\addHelper.js:149:35
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) (node:11012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:11012) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Did u try to delete manually?

Comment: I had deleted cordova entirely and reinstalled it to the same error.

Comment: When u cmd cordova platform add android what android version will be adding to project?

Comment: I updated my question to show what happens if I try to re-add the Android platform. I am trying to pull whatever latest working android version there is which I always accomplish with cordova platform add android

Comment: Delete the platform folder in project and cmd cordova platform add android@6.3.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured this out. I had to use rm instead of remove like so:

> cordova platform rm android

Not sure why, would love for someone to elaborate, the cordova docs contain cordova platform remove

Comment: Just an *FYI* for future readers, this works with ionic too. I was prepending `ionic` before the commands and it kept on failing when I omitted `ionic` and ran the above it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. The solution was to point away from the android directory in Windows Explorer before removing the platform.